Redirect sub pages in openlitespeed server
I want to redirect subpages to main page i.e: https://mywebsite.com/new-page/ to https://mywebsite.com
So i tried below .htaccess but I have openlitspeed server and this doesn't fully support every .htaccess rule
RewriteEngine on

# Ensure we rewrite only requests for the subdomain "suspend.impaktt.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^suspend\.impaktt\.com$ [NC]

# Check if the requested resource is not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Redirect everything to the root of the subdomain
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://suspend.impaktt.com/$1 [L,R=301]

I have tested on htaccess tester https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/
and found my below RULE does not work
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://suspend.impaktt.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Can any of you please help me to write alterate htaccess rule on openlitspeed

Replace + with *, then restart the web server and it should work.
